# why Service is not taking by the Service implementation?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, autowired

this is my service:

this is my service implementation:

```
@Service
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {

    @Autowired()
    private CategoryRepo categoryRepo;
    

}
```

and this is the output result:

```
Description:

Field categoryRepo in com.example.demo.services.impl.CategoryServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repositories.CategoryRepo' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repositories.CategoryRepo' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: how could I provide. stackoverfow only says too many codes. so i deleted some of the codes on question body.

Answer (score 0):

For defining your `CategoryRepo` as a bean it should extend `CrudRepository`

Answer (score 0):

The repo which you've defined in your code must extend JpaRepsitory. Inorder, to qualify it as a been and for better understanding of your please share your Repository file once here.